# Implement Admob Mediation SDK instead of standard Admob SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, admob

I have implemented the standard stand alone `Admob SDK` successfully in my app and works fine.

But now, I want to implement the **`Admob Mediation SDK`**.

I also want to know what is the `difference` between them?

**How can I implement the Admob Mediation SDK?**

Thank you,....

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a different SDK, mediated and non-mediated ads both use the same SDK. There will however be a different Admob ID for mediated ads. The mediation is a setting you need to enable in your Admob account.

Please see: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/mediation for detailed instructions of how to enable mediation

Mediation just lets you control the fill rates between ad networks. For example you may configure the mediation to:

- Display iAds 30% of the time
- Display Admob ads 50% of the time
- Display a custom advert 20% of the time